# Get content with RegEx between braces and a keyword

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm just facing with a problem, what I cannot solve it.
I tried to build up my regex pattern which has to be get the content between braces but if only an exact keyword is stands before the open brace.

```
(?<=(?:\testlist\b)|(?:){)((.*?)(?=}))
```

The whole content itself may contains many blocks (which are always beginning with a keyword), like:

```
nodelist{
...
...
}
testlist
{
...
...
}
```

With the above pattern I can get each of node contents but I would like to specify in regex that only 'testlist' node's content has to be grabbed.
(Position of braces are different by design because I would like to get the content even if the braces are in the same line as the keyword or no matter, how many line breaks contains after it)

Does anyone any idea, how can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What language/engine/platform?

Comment: Currently Powershell 4 on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
(?s)testlist\s*{(.*?)}
```

This matches `testlist` literally, followed by spaces and a literal opening brace. `(.*?)` captures everything until the next closing brace.

Usage:

```
PS C:\Users\greg> 'nodelist{
>> ...
>> ...
>> }
>> testlist
>> {
>> ...
>> ...
>> }' -match '(?s)testlist\s*{(.*?)}'
True
PS C:\Users\greg> $Matches.0
testlist
{
...
...
}
PS C:\Users\greg> $Matches.1

...
...

PS C:\Users\greg>
```

If you want a full match instead of a capture group:

```
PS C:\Users\greg> 'nodelist{
>> ...
>> ...
>> }
>> testlist
>> {
>> ...
>> ...
>> }' -match '(?s)(?<=testlist\s*{).*?(?=})'
True
PS C:\Users\greg> $Matches.0

...
...

PS C:\Users\greg>
```

Comment: Even if it does not return the content as a full match but as group match it's quite a simply and short solution which I may use. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with getting the full match is that the lookbehind is variable length, which many regex engines don't support. Powershell does, so I added an alternate version. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fully satisfied with this answer and solution!